# Removing item(s) from a subarray inside a mongo document in a nodejs server

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Herebelow is a part of code and mongoose schema for a nodejs server of a chat app.
When a user sends a message the message is saved in two documents. One in the senders and the other in the receivers.

In the JS code given below I am trying to delete the sender message from the sender document and the receiver document.
Deleting the sender message doc was straight forward :   `Message.findByIdAndDelete({_id:userID}).catch((err) => { console.log(err.message);});`

As for the removing the sender item in the receiver document I managed to find the the receiver docs that contain the senderID but when I try to pull the item from the users list in the receiver doc I am getting the following exception:

```
node:events:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: user.pull is not a function
```

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Full JS code:

```
const deleteMessage = (userID) => {

  console.log('userID delete : ' +userID)
  //Delete message collection corresponding to the userID
  Message.findByIdAndDelete({_id:userID}).catch((err) => { console.log(err.message);});

    //Delete messages corresponding to the userID from the receiver' message list
  Message.find({users:{$elemMatch:{ _id:userID}}}, (err,doc)=>{
    console.log(doc);

    doc.forEach((user)=> {

      user.pull({_id:userID})
      doc.save();
    })
    
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
}
```

message schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const contentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    isMy: Boolean,
    message: String,
    createdAt: Date,
  }
);

const receiverSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  messages: [contentSchema],
});

const messageSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  users: [receiverSchema],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Message", messageSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **use** pull **directly** on **collection**, assuming **user** is your collection you can use **findOneAndUpdate** like below -

```
user.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {    //here find that user
          $pull: {_id: userId}   //use your reference like message id or something
})
```

let me know if you want more clarity. Thank you.

Comment: How do I update more than one document in the collection that contains that userID. Also the there can be multiple userIDs which a given document in a array

Comment: I was able to to do what you are trying to say I will check if I still have that piece of code I don't remember as it has been long time